# How can i load image path in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I wanna load the result image from index and display it. `resultID` is image name (1000.png) and the image path from index.csv is `dataset\1000.png`. So what should i change `result`  variable following:

````
    result = cv2.imread(args["result_path"] + "/" + resultID)
    cv2.imshow("Result", result)
    cv2.waitKey(0)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `.png` at the path of the image you want to read. If you call the `cv2.imread()` this way, I think it might work:

```
img_path = args["result_path"] + "/" + str(resultID) + ".png"
result = cv2.imread(img_path) 
cv2.imshow("Result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You could also use the `.format()` method that inputs variable results into a string to get a cleaner code:

```
img_path = "{}/{}.png".format(args["result_path"], resultID)
```

You can find [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/) the basic syntax to show an image using `cv2.imshow()`.

```
# Python program to explain cv2.imread() method
  
# importing cv2 
import cv2
  
# path
path = r'C:\Users\Rajnish\Desktop\geeksforgeeks.png'
  
# Using cv2.imread() method
img = cv2.imread(path)
  
# Displaying the image
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer. After reading it, i found my true problem, i asked wrong question. Anyway, thank u for hard working, i appreciate so much